# Paginated datatable with gmap markers in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a paginated datatable and would like to add all the items in the current page as markers in a gmap. The iterable item in the datatable has getters for longitude and latitude. Is there an easy way doing this in prime faces?

Thanks,
Dwayne